# AVAssetsLibrary writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum not working.

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, nsdata, alassetslibrary

**Problem:**
I've got some trouble using `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` of `AVAssetsLibrary`

**Question:**
I want to use this over `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` to avoid possible compression of the photo library

Here is my **code sample** below :

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.imageView.image.CGImage));
uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
NSData *dataTOSave = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:CFDataGetLength(pixelData) freeWhenDone:NO];

ALAssetsLibrary *assetLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLib writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:dataTOSave metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}];
```

Error log in the completion block print `null`, but nothing appears in the photo library of my iPhone.
But now, if I used `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` it works great :

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLib writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[self.imageView.image CGImage] metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}];
```

Error log still print `null`, and the image appears in the photo Library.

Note that I did this test with a small jpg image (250*333).

Does someone have any idea of why the first sample not working ? And why no errors is shown in the completion block ?